# Connecting 2 side by side downspouts at base

Tags: exterior, downspout

Because of the roof lines of my house, there are two downspouts side by side that ends at my patio. I’d like to reorient them to turn instead of face forward. I’m not sure how to handle that they’re so close.
[image]

I was thinking I could put an elbow on the left pipe and attach an extension. Then I could cut a hole iN the elbow/extension to accept the right pipe. They’re 2x3.

I couldn’t find any examples of ppl doing this, or products that meet my needs either. Do we think this would work? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Have one down pipe longer than the other.

The elbow on the short pipe will ride on top of the elbow of the long pipe.

The pipes will be over/under instead of side by side.

Comment: Right, but they should terminate side-by-side and not one on top. A slight tweak to the angles accommodates this.

Comment: Yes to this, don't combine the pipes!  Unfortunately the left pipe is already cut a little shorter than the right, which is backwards to what you want, so your best bet is to cut the right pipe around the level of the top of your red scribble, leave the left pipe, and put right hand elbows on  both.  If the pipe going off to the right will be long, you could combine them both into a larger pipe, say a 4" round PVC one.

Comment: Also, put some large rocks on both sides of the horizontal extensions otherwise these will become victims of lawn mowers VERY quickly.

Comment: Does it matter than one roof is tiny? Can they combine then?

Comment: if one is tiny and doesn't output much then you can probably combine them.

Comment: You can even use one of these guys to rotate the orientation of the outlet: https://www.gutterworks.com/shop-online/convert-a-bow  If the one roof is indeed really small, you could use a wye connector to connect them to a single outlet: https://www.gutterworks.com/shop-online/y-downspout-funnels